# bootstrap css doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I use gem twitter-bootstrap-rails in my ruby on rails project.
But the css class "icon-white" doesn't work.
I can see definiton of "icon-white" in gem toolkit.But in chrome dev tools,I can't find it.
Why?
How to solve?

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<div class = "icon-user icon-white"></div>
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
<% end -%>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. We can't see what is going wrong unless you post some code.

Comment: I just want to test.Code is here

Comment: Just a tip: If a particular answer is helpful in solving your problem, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of it. Also, please don't forget to do the same for your previous questions, wherever applicable. You can find them in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1274171/mariodu).

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Icons are meant for the `<i>` element.

```
<i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>
```

They will not work on a `<div>`

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

(Scroll down to "How to use")

Comment: @MarioDu - From the bootstrap docs: "There are also styles available for inverted (white) icons, made ready with one extra class. We will specifically enforce this class on hover and active states for nav and dropdown links." You need to hover this icon to see any change.

Comment: I just try to comment "@import @import "fontawesome";".It works well.

Comment: How to use fontawesome?Use it to do what?

Comment: @MarioDu the documentation should tell you exactly what to do. It also gives you detailed examples and what they do.

Comment: @MarioDu if this answered your question, you should mark your question as answered